# Android - EditText not editable and not selectable

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In my activity code I have these lines

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

What I want to achieve is a `EditText` uneditable and unselectable.
With the previous line I try to achieve the second option, but it'doesn't work. The `EditText` is still selectable.

In order to make the `EditText` uneditable I have not found any method such as `setEditable` or similar. I read about setting `InputType` but I had no success.

However the unselectable constraint can be weakened. My main goal is that the text inside the `EditText` cannot change for any reason. For these reason the `EditRext` could be selectable but I want that no user can cut the text.

**I want no XML but only Java code. All these things are needed to to programmatically.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry guys, at least for my setup (Sdk Version 25 with AppCompatActivity)

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

will still let me push the return button of the virtual keyboard, adding lines to the text. If you add

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

this behaviour stopps, however, the text is greyed out.

Therefore, I think the following would be a better solution:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: The magic number `0` in the `setInputType()` method, what does it mean?

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) say: >"There is no content type. The text is not editable."

Comment: I tried. The only input type seems to make the `EditText` not clickable and not long-clickable. I don't know if `setClickable(false)` and `setLongClickable(false)` are unnecessary now.

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce what @Vin said earlier about the click and the long click. If no one intervenes soon, I will take out lines 2 and 3 from my answer. Lines 1 and 4 suffice.

Comment: It seems that with only line 4 (`setInputType(0)`) the `EditText` is not editable and not selectable.

Comment: `setFocusable(false)` is only if anyone would that all `EditText`s are not highlited when are clicked.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine; just set focusable property of your edittext to "false" and you are done.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextInput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:cursorVisible="true">
    </EditText>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. `setFocusable(false)` is the way.

Comment: Wait wait wait. `setFocusable(false)` is not enough. Because text can be pasted into the`EditText`, and this is not a good thing.

Comment: @KalaBalik It doesn't matter means that the solution is understandable. In this case `android:focusable="false"` is exactly `setFocusable(false)`. Sometimes XML is not fully translatable to Java code, in that case I will not accepted the question.

Comment: Perfect for making an EditText that is actually not editable. This answer also avoids the keyboard showing.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the following code:

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setClickable(false);
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Which should prevent interacting with the `EditText`. Read more about the `View` class here since `EditText` extends from it:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusable(boolean)

Comment: `setEnabled(false)` disable the `EditText`. It's a drastic solution.

Comment: `setClickable(false)` seems to do no difference. `setFocusable(false)` is the right way.

Comment: @Vin only using `setFocusable()` does not disable it, a user can still paste data to the `EditText`.

Comment: I didn't think it. Thank you.

Comment: Instead to use `setEnabled(false)`. I used `setFocusable(false)`, `setClickable(false)` and `setLongClickable(false)`. This seems to prevent text pasting  inside the `EditText`