# How to make Auto complete Text view Editable or not-Editable?

Tags: android, contenteditable, autocompletetextview

I want to make Auto complete TextView Editable or not editable according to my condition.

I made  Autocomplete text view as Editable

```
    constituency.setEnabled(true);
    constituency.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    constituency.setClickable(true);
```

but it's not working.
can anyone please help me?

Comment: how is it duplicate of that question?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the referenced question. While this question is about disabling an AutoCompleteTextView altogether, the other question is about disabling the DropDown of an AutoCompleteTextView.

Answer (score 10):

To disable an `EditText` (autocomplete or not) use `editText.setInputType(0)`. See my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895714/android-edittext-not-editable-and-not-selectable/46896419#46896419).

For re-enabling that `EditText` inquire the value of the input type *prior* to disabling it, save it in a variable, for example in `int safe = editText.getInputType()` and put the variable back in its place like so: `editText.setInputType(safe)`. In order to regain focus, add `editText.clearFocus()` and `editText.requestFocus()`.

Comment: how to make it editable after this not editable operation?

Comment: Depends on the [input type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) you need, for example: `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE);`

Comment: Will try and update if it works for me or not

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Have you tried `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`, as you used it when first configuring your `EditText`?

Comment: YES, it is also not working for me

Comment: Can you describe HOW it is not working?

Comment: I made a condition of boolean . when it is true, Then added like **myautocompleteTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE‌​);**      else if it is false then I made like **myautocompleteTextView.setInputType(0)**

Comment: I was asking you to describe how my solution does not do what you want to achieve. What happens when your condition is true (again)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162882/discussion-between-basha-and-kalabalik).

Answer (score 6):

may be you are looking for this one.

```
education.setKeyListener(null);
```

for setting it back just put it in some method and call

```
education.setKeyListener(TextKeyListener.getInstance());
```

Comment: how to make it editable ?

Comment: you want to make it editable or not ?

Comment: want to know how to editable and not editable

Comment: then simply add the listener again

Comment: will try and update u

Comment: yeah i have also updated

Comment: it made my app not editable

Comment: yeah this is what you want i guess?

Comment: No, I want to know first not editable, and then according to my condition it should be editable. but your suggestion is not working for me

Comment: okay, got it but also you can make it editable again by enabling the listener according to input type as we have digit listener which listens digit only ,text listener and so on.

Comment: set key listener is working a treat. thank u 

Answer (score 3):

You can just set `constituency.setEnabled(boolean)`, to true or false.

Comment: by adding that editTextis enabling and disabling . but after it is enabled to **true** , then it is  not editable